Using the RG equations to find the free energy scaling form of the 2D Ising Model
i am trying to calculate the scaling form of the free energy of the 2D Ising model, starting from it's RG equations:
$$\frac{d u_I}{dl} = 2 u_I + u_t^2$$
$$\frac{d u_t}{dl} = u_t$$
$$\frac{d u_h}{dl} = \frac{15}{8} u_h$$
where $u_I$ is the identity scaling field, $u_t$ the temperature scaling field, $u_h$ the magnetic one and $ l = ln(b)$, with b being the RG scale.
So i found:
$$u_h = \alpha_h \cdot e^{15/8 \cdot l}$$
$$u_t = \alpha_t \cdot e^{l}$$
$$u_I = \alpha_t^2 \cdot e^{2l} \cdot l + \alpha_I \cdot e^{2l}$$
What i now know is that the (singular) scaling form of the free energy has the following form in general:
$$ f_{sing} (\tau, h) = \tau^{2-\alpha} \cdot g_f (\frac{h}{\tau^{\Delta}}) $$
where $\Delta$ is the Gap exponent.
From there i would like to calculate the specific heat and other thermodynamic quantities, where $C \propto -\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial \tau^2}$.
The problem is, i don't quite understand how to get to the free energy with the three scaling fields i got here.
I understand that in essence the scaling form of the free energy is dependent on $\tau$ and $h$ but i do not understand how to get there using the scaling fields corresponding to these. I am honestly even a bit confused by the concept of scaling fields here in general, as i didn't really study field theory yet.
Could maybe anyone explain to me the link between the scaling form and the scaling fields i calculated here? Or maybe point me in the right direction with some literature you could recommend to me about this topic? I was reading John Cardy's book about Scaling and Renormalization in Statistical Physics, but it is very general and I struggle in understanding it.
Thank you!

Did you look at equations (3.29)-(3.34) of Cardy's Scaling and Renormalization in Statistical Physics? He computes the critical exponents in terms of the RG eigenvalues.
